# Twig (non-symfony) global variables

Tags: php, twig

It's been a while since i've been working on something. I use a very old template parser and i thought it was time to move on to Twig.

It looks very good and would love to work with it but i run into some problems which i can't seem to find a solution. I seen a few regarding my question but won't work and most of the time they are with symfony.

So let me explain;

I use my index.php as main page (frontcontroller) and include my files into it. Since i use a right menu that display login information etc... that will be displayed in the base.html, thus show in every template... i need to find a way to set an array of globals in my index.php file.

I know there is a $twig->addGlobal('test', 'This is my test); but would need to add much of them.

There is that Extention with getGlobals() but you need to manually add them in the array provided there and i can't find a way to pass an array form my index to it. Besides if i look into it, it say it's deprecated.

Maybe i look over it or Twig is not the solution for me?
any help is welcome here, and thanks in advance!

Nico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Twig extension:

```php
class MyTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension implements Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface
{
    private $some;

    private $data;

    public function __construct($some, $data) {
        $this->some = $some;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getGlobals()
    {
        $globals = array();

        // .. create globals by using the properties defined above

        return $globals;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The getGlobals method is indeed deprecated, but in the code they say:

> @deprecated since 1.23 (to be removed in 2.0), implement Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface instead

So using the getGlobals method is not deprecated if you implement the Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface.

When you create the Twig_Environment add the extension like this:

```php
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new MyTwigExtension($passYour, $data));
```

So basically you pass all the data necessary for creating the globals to the constructor of your extension.

Comment: The MyTwigExtension class I posted above just contains the necessary parts to answer the question. Of course you have to implement all methods required. What exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I had to pass in getName function or it gave me an error. How do i pass my array into it? example: 

$global_array = [
 'var1'  => 'output1',
 'var2'  => 'output2',
 //.... ... 
 ];

Comment: Use the constructor parameters. I described it in my answer.

Comment: silly me! it works. I took me a frustrating week to find the right answer! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -3):

How about passing [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) to Twig_Enviroment?

$TwigLoader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem([...]);

$Twig = new Twig_Environment($TwigLoader,
    array(
        'globals' => $GLOBALS
    )
);

then in Twig template:

{{ globals.your_variable_name }}